# Need to combine 2 files having different word list size

Tags: bash, shell, concatenation

I need to combine 2 files of bash script that are having word lists with different word counts and I want to combine them as shown below.

**File 1:**

```
word1
word2
word3
```

**File 2:**

```
8.8.8.8
4.4.4.4
4.4.2.2
5.5.5.5
```

**Desired Output:**

```
word1,8.8.8.8
word1,4.4.4.4
word1,4.4.2.2
word1,5.5.5.5
word2,8.8.8.8
word2,4.4.4.4
word2,4.4.2.2
word2,5.5.5.5
word3,8.8.8.8
word3,4.4.4.4
word3,4.4.2.2
word3,5.5.5.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a high enough field number (like 100) that is not contained in your files and (ab)use `join` to produce the cartesian product

```sh
join -j 100 file1.txt file2.txt
```

```
 word1 8.8.8.8
 word1 4.4.4.4
 word1 4.4.2.2
 word1 5.5.5.5
 word2 8.8.8.8
 word2 4.4.4.4
 word2 4.4.2.2
 word2 5.5.5.5
 word3 8.8.8.8
 word3 4.4.4.4
 word3 4.4.2.2
 word3 5.5.5.5
```

Edit: In order to have a comma as column separator, name it using the `-t` option, and to have the output not start with that separator (previously a space, now the comma), make the ordering explicit using the `-o` option:

```sh
join -j 100 -t, -o 1.1,2.1 file1.txt file2.txt
```

```
word1,8.8.8.8
word1,4.4.4.4
word1,4.4.2.2
word1,5.5.5.5
word2,8.8.8.8
word2,4.4.4.4
word2,4.4.2.2
word2,5.5.5.5
word3,8.8.8.8
word3,4.4.4.4
word3,4.4.2.2
word3,5.5.5.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. This does the half work. I need to use "," as well in order to make it easier for me to open it in excel.

Comment: @DrGeek Then give a field separator using `-t,` but this also puts a comma in the first position. To counter that, also add the output order using `-o 1.1,2.1`. So altogether it should read `join -j 100 -t, -o 1.1,2.1 file1.txt file2.txt`

Comment: It worked as expected thanks for your hep mate but the result that I got is as below. Now, Need to remove blank spaces and then combine the files.

Result that I get is:

word1,8.8.8.8
word1,2.2.2.2
word1,3.3.3.3
word1,1.1.1.1
word1,
word2,8.8.8.8
word2,2.2.2.2
word2,3.3.3.3
word2,1.1.1.1
word2,

Desired output: as given in the first post

This is happening because when I paste wordlist in the files, sometimes space is getting added. So, I want this blank space to be ignored and only word on the wordlist are to be processed and give me the result that I expect.

Comment: It is difficult to read your formatting if you don't mark your examples as code (read how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)). That said, if you are asking about the column separator, I should have answered it in my previous comment, but I also edited my answer to reflect it. If, however, you have a different input ("when I paste wordlist in the files, sometimes space is getting added") for a new task ("how to delete the spaces", instead of "how to generate the cartesian product"), then consider asking a new question with the new conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify and gain flexibility by using `awk` to read both files values into separate indexed arrays and then in the `END` rule, simply loop over the stored values outputting in the format you desire, e.g.

```sh
awk '
  FNR==NR { f1[++n] = $0; next }        # save file_1 in array f1
  { f2[++m] = $0 }                      # save file_2 in array f2
  END {
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)                # loop over all f1 values
      for(j=1; j<=m; j++)               # loop over all f2 values
        printf "%s,%s\n", f1[i], f2[j]  # output f1[],f2[]
  }
' file_1 file_2
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in `file_1` and `file_2` you would have:

```
$ awk '
>   FNR==NR { f1[++n] = $0; next }        # save file_1 in array f1
>   { f2[++m] = $0 }                      # save file_2 in array f2
>   END {
>     for (i=1; i<=n; i++)                # loop over all f1 values
>       for(j=1; j<=m; j++)               # loop over all f2 values
>         printf "%s,%s\n", f1[i], f2[j]  # output f1[],f2[]
>   }
> ' file_1 file_2
word1,8.8.8.8
word1,4.4.4.4
word1,4.4.2.2
word1,5.5.5.5
word2,8.8.8.8
word2,4.4.4.4
word2,4.4.2.2
word2,5.5.5.5
word3,8.8.8.8
word3,4.4.4.4
word3,4.4.2.2
word3,5.5.5.5
```

**Using Bash**

You can do the exact same thing in a bash script reading both files into array using `readarray` (synonym to `mapfile`), e.g.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

usage() {  ## simple function to output error and usage
  [ -n "$1" ] && printf "error: %s\n" "$1"
  printf "usage: %s file_1 file_2\n" "${0##*/}"
}

## validate filenames provided in first 2 arguments exist and are non-empty
[ -s "$1" ] || { usage "file $1 not found or empty"; exit 1; }
[ -s "$2" ] || { usage "file $2 not found or empty"; exit 1; }

readarray -t f1 < "$1"    # read file_1 int array f1
readarray -t f2 < "$2"    # read file_2 int array f2

for i in "${f1[@]}"; do         ## loop over f1
  for j in "${f2[@]}"; do       ## loop over f2
    printf "%s,%s\n" "$i" "$j"  ## output combined result
  done
done
```

(**note:** `awk` will likely provide better performance)

**Example Use/Output**

With the script saved as `cmbfiles.sh` you would have:

```
$ bash cmbfiles.sh file_1 file_2
word1,8.8.8.8
word1,4.4.4.4
word1,4.4.2.2
word1,5.5.5.5
word2,8.8.8.8
word2,4.4.4.4
word2,4.4.2.2
word2,5.5.5.5
word3,8.8.8.8
word3,4.4.4.4
word3,4.4.2.2
word3,5.5.5.5
```

Comment: An improvement wrt memory consumption could be to read in just one file as an array, and already produce output while iterating over the lines read from the other file. This would eliminate the double loop, and shift the processing to the `FNR!=NR` case in `awk`, or make the other `readarray` to a `while read` loop in the `bash` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk -v OFS="," -v ORS="\r\n" '                  # set comma as field separator, CRLF as record separator
    NR==FNR && NF>0 {a[++n]=$0; next}           # read file2.txt skipping blang lines
    NF>0 {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print $0, a[i]}  # print line of file1.txt appending the lines of file2.txt
' file2.txt file1.txt
```

- It skips blank lines in the input file.
- It appends Windows line endings considering to be opened with Excel.